# Confused about how to fill an array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I would like to fill out a 2-dimensional array randomly .But I dont know how to assign .This is what i have yet

```
      Random rnd = new Random();
        int x = rnd.Next(0, 3);
        int y = rnd.Next(0, 3);

        int[,] array=new int[2,2];
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                   ?? I have no idea

            }
        }
```

Comment: You access the array like this: array[i,j] = rnd.Next(0,3); for example. I suggest you read a bit more about C# syntax first.

Comment: array[i,k] = //int value

Comment: Are you trying to fill every field in the array with a random value, or randomly choose one field in the array and assign it some (specific or random) value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this.

```
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int[,] array=new int[2,2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
               array[i,j] = rnd.Next(0,100);

        }
    }
```

Comment: thakn you for everyone

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this. But i wonder why you are generating 2 random numbers

```
 Random rnd = new Random();
 int x = rnd.Next(0, 3);
 int y = rnd.Next(0, 3);

 int[,] array=new int[2,2];
 for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
 {
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
           array[i,j] = yourvalue;
    }
 }
```

Comment: No reason just practise friend